# How to push view controller with transparency mode?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, alpha-transparency

I am trying to push a view controller with transparency mode.

This is my code:

```
SearchViewController * searchViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewController"];
searchViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.7f];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];
```

Something i did mistake find out and help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You have to use custom transitions

Comment: Can you explain it how ??

Comment: you want the transparent background or transparencey mode

Comment: @KishoreKumar could you provide any images that describe your issue?

Comment: @WetSweater previous view controller have images so when i push a new view controller i need to show the things with blur transparency effect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro transparency mode needed

Comment: use `searchViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;searchViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; // fade

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://medium.com/@A2HGO/blurred-translucent-ios-navigation-controller-transitions-f38934204f46#.fwggl81td

Comment: @KishoreKumar do you solve this?

Comment: @SergeyDi u have to play with alpha

Comment: @KishoreKumar I tried, but it shows black screen.

Answer (score -2):

You have to set modalPresentationStyle with overFullScreen value

```
let viewController = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil)
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -3):

In iOS the default color of background is black.
So you navigation controller has a black background.

If you push a controller, you current controller will be replaced by your new one. If the new one have a transparent color you will see the view of your navigation.

If I understand you want your first controller to be still visible ?
If yes, then you should use :

```
SearchViewController * searchViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewController"];
searchViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.7f];
[self presentViewController:searchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can also use a custom segue to have the cor

Comment: Yes I tried this before working ,but my case is from push ->view controller is it possible ?

Comment: It depend: Do you want still see you first controller ? If yes you have to use presentViewController or something like steveen zoleko suggest : https://medium.com/@A2HGO/blurred-translucent-ios-navigation-controller-transitions-f38934204f46#.fwggl81td